# Lookup GINI by year and country

Tags: r

This takes a dataframe as an argument, looks at all pairs of two columns in that data frame (country and year) and returns a column value of that pair in another data frame (the gini number).

```
get_gini <- function(year, country){
    GINI = 0
    SUBSETTED_WITH_COUNTRY_NAME_NOW_WITH_YEAR <- inequality[inequality$Code== country & inequality$Year== year,]
    GINI <- mean(as.numeric(SUBSETTED_WITH_COUNTRY_NAME_NOW_WITH_YEAR$Gini))

    country_and_year<- totes_data[totes_data$totes_data == country & totes_data$year == year,] 
    country_and_year$GiniState1<-GINI
    output<-country_and_year$GiniState1
    output<-output[1]
    if (is.na(output)){
      output=0
    }
    else {
      output = output
    }
    assign("ginilist",output, envir=globalenv())
    rbind(output,ginilist)
}
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of the data frame.

Answer (score 3):

With the `data.table` package, you can do a quick join and get the gini coefficient much easier. This solution is also vectorized, so you can call it with something like `gini(2000:2004, 'USA')` to get the gini coefficients for the USA for years 2000-2004.

It is also good practice to include the data in your function call, so you don't use objects from the global environment within the function call. This function outputs the entire `data.table`, but you can also just use the gini coefficient as output, if you add `[, GINI]` at the end.

```
gini <- function(year, country, data = inequality){
  require(data.table)
  setkey(setDT(data), 'Code', 'Year')[J(Code = country, Year=year), 
                                        list(GINI = mean(as.numeric(Gini))), 
                                        by=list(Code, Year)]
}
```